# Recursive async function not defined in react componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, recursion, async-await, iife

I am trying to define an Async recursive function inside my app's main componentDidMount component. The function is supposed to keep polling the network for changes in an API (done through the this.refreshNetwork() method.

The promise is meant to work as a delay.

```
componentDidMount() {
  (async function networkCheck(a){ 
      await this.refreshNetwork(); 
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,a)); 
      await networkCheck(500);
    }.bind(this)());
}
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
Unhandled promise rejection ReferenceError: "networkCheck is not defined"
```

I don't understand how the function could possible not be defined inside itself

Comment: What environment are you using? [It seems to be working fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/8yy61lwkq9).

Comment: Also, it's not good enough to be used any way. Recursive IIFE is harder to test. It won't be interrupted on unmount.